# Flutter : how to access key inside a custom widget

Tags: flutter, widget

I'm currently trying to separate 1 big main file into multiple widgets files, particularly in this case is the Custom Appbar widget itself.

in the main file, i have a key argument in scaffold of the whole widget, to use it in the **ontap event** of one of the button in the app bar, **to open the drawer widget**.

when refactoring this, i wonder on how to use the **key.currentState?.openDrawer(),** in the separated widget.

main.dart file (origin)

```
 class _Page1State extends State<_Page1> {
   Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
      key: _key,
      body: Container .....
      .....
        ElevatedButton(
         onPressed: () => key.currentState?.openDrawer(),
      .....

 }
```

appbar.dart file (separating attempt)

```
 class _Appbar extends StatefulWidget {
   const _Appbar({
     required this.deviceConnector,
     Key? key,
   }) : super(key: key);

   @override
   _AppbarState createState() => _AppbarState();
 }

 class _AppbarState extends State<_Appbar> {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Row(
       children: [
         Row(
           children: [
             ElevatedButton(
              child: Row(
                children: [Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png',)],
            ),
            onPressed: ()  {
              //
            })
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Row(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          child: Icon(
              Icons.settings,
              size: 38,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          onPressed: () => key.currentState?.openDrawer(),
        ),
      ],
    
    ],
  );
}
```

}

Comment: ``widget.key.currentState?.openDrawer() `` instead of ``key.currentState?.openDrawer()``

Comment: if i use widget.key.currentState? - i will get an error of the receiver can be 'null'
and if i use widget.key?currentState - i will get an error of getter currentState is not define for the type 'Key'

Comment: just pass the ``_key`` reference from your ``main.dart`` file to this widget.

Comment: thanks, but im not sure how to do that, but i solved it using Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),